# is this the right way to do login logic in meteor to display a simple "invalid login" message?

Tags: meteor

I started this example project to learn meteor:

https://github.com/andrewarrow/question-raven/

I'm trying to duplicated a popular question/answer site functionality just to learn meteor.

Above my login form I have this in the template:

```
 {{#if invalid }}
<div style="background-color: yellow; padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;">
login invalid, please try again.
</div>
{{/if}}
```

and I'm starting the login logic like this:

```
Template.hello.events = {
  'click #login' : function () {
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    if (false) {
      Session.set('user_id', 1);
    } else {
      Session.set('invalid', 1);
    }
  }
};
```

Then in order for the invalid variable to work in the template I have this function:

```
Template.hello.invalid = function () {
  return Session.get('invalid') != null;
};
```

Is this the right way to do this?  Does every variable the template references have to be a function?  Should I use the Session store to record a login was invalid so a function can return true/false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - you can't do it (yet).  But I'm sure the meteor team is working hard on it, since it's a big hole in the framework at the moment.

The way you're doing it in this example would be insecure in any client-side framework since you're setting the value of a javascript variable to enforce authentication.  I can run `Session.set('invalid', null);` in the chrome console and log myself in.

The canonical way of logging in is to have the server hash the password and compare it to the username/password table in the database, if it's valid create a session token in another database table with an expires datetime, then give the session token to the browser to send you with future requests (usually stored in a cookie).  This doesn't work in Meteor because the client has full read/write access to any collection in the database.

You could, potentially, have a completely separate database running that Meteor doesn't know about, and set up meteor functions on the server that access it with node.js code (pybassing meteor Collections altogether).  You could pub/sub only the public data from that database to see the data auto-update in your client.  It would be really messy, and I'm not even positive it would work - you're much better off not using meteor if you need authentication right now.

A partial solution (and very easy to implement) is to use HTTP authentication.  It doesn't work for a user system since nobody can sign up, but it would keep strangers from seeing your code/ accessing your database.

Comment: thanks danny, exactly the information I was looking for.  One more question though; when I create a reference like {{#if foo }} in the template.  Does foo have to be a function?  Is there anyway to just define a simple variable to be used in the template?

Comment: You can, but only if it's a constant.  E.g. putting `Template.hello.foo = true;` in your js code works fine, but probably isn't very useful.  For anything that you want to be dynamic and update based on pub/sub you have to wrap it in an anonymous function like you did in your example.

Comment: This was a great answer when posted, but now Meteor has builtin login support; see @cmather's answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can now use the accounts-base, accounts-ui, and accounts-* (various login services) packages for this. You could use Session to create a reactive notification for a failed login, after calling the loginWith* method and providing a callback that takes an error if something bad happens. Example:

```
Template.hello.events = {
  'click #login' : function () {
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, function (err) {
      if (err) Session.set("loginError", true);
    });
  }
};
```

The new docs explain it pretty well:

http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_loginwithpassword

Comment: And you can even get started with [a full login system with one line of code](http://docs.meteor.com/#accountsui)!

Answer (score 0):

If you want additional details of the login error, Meteor actually passes a 'reason' string in the error argument to the callback of Meteor.loginWithPassword. This is how I implement the Meteor.loginWithPassword :

```
Meteor.loginWithPassword(username, password, function(error) {
  if(error !== undefined){
    setAlert('error', 'Error in processing login. ' + error.reason + '.');
  }
});
```